# Invalid Scope When Trying To Create Use GoogleAccountCredential With ARC-Welder on Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I have an Android app that I'm trying to run under Chrome ARC (via ARC-Welder).  I've created all the OAuth2 IDs and changed my APK to substitute the Chrome client-id if it's running under ARC (build=="chromium").  However, I still get "INVALID_SCOPE" exceptions from `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`.

The actual "scope" value is:

```
audience:oauth2:client_id:numbers-numbersandletters.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

The actual exception, hot from `logcat` is:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: INVALID_SCOPE
  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
  ...
```

The code making this request is:

```
final String clientid = isChromeArc() ? CHROME_CLIENT_ID  : WEB_CLIENT_ID;
googleCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this, "server:client_id:" + clientid);

final String accountname = settingsPreferences.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
googleCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountname);
assert googleCredential.getSelectedAccount() != null;
assert !googleCredential.getSelectedAccount().equals("");

if (googleCredential.getToken() == null) ...  // <== exception here
```

Lastly, the meta-data given to ARC-Welder during the creation process is:

```
{
  "usePlayServices": ["maps"],
  "crx_key": "MII...verylongbase64string...AB"
}
```

*Is there something different I need to do to be able to connect to my App-Engine "endpoints" or is this simply not yet supported?*

Answer (score 1):

[Cross client authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) is not supported on ARC (just not yet).  Here is an related [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297129) for tracking.